# Wrapped reference-counting, questions about move-semantics

Tags: c++, move-semantics, reference-counting

I'm working on a class that acts as a scope helper for reference-counted objects. The interface should allow to use the class as follows:

```
{
    Handle<String> s = Handle<String>::New("Hello, World!");
    s = s->Concat(Handle<String>::New(" My name is Peter"));
}
```

while `String` is the class that contains the reference-count.

I am not very familar with move semantics and I was unable to find a concrete paper which sates the conditions that apply for move-semantics. Basically, what I am wondering about is:

Can `this` be an object that was already initialized in the move-constructor? Because if that is the case, i can't tell apart if the member in my `Handle` class that points to the `String` contains some garbage value or is actually pointing to a real `String`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. `*this` is never "already initialized" in a constructor. A move constructor is just a constructor taking a single argument of type rvalue reference to the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's possible using placement construction, but doing so is asking for trouble. I don't even know why I mentioned it. Short answer: No, it cannot. Move constructors only differ from other constructors in the type of values they accept.